# Destroying an object after it is out of sight?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project wherein I am loading two road planes (one after another) to create an endless road. I also have a script attached to the camera which creates trees. All of the code works perfectly fine,  the trees are created correctly, but I want to destroy them after they are out of the camera's sight.

My code:

```
void generateSideTress()
{
    GameObject treeObj = GameObject.Instantiate(sideTres[Random.Range(0, sideTres.Length - 1)]) as GameObject;
    treeObj.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-80,-60), 0, playerObj.transform.position.z + 780);
    treeObj.transform.Rotate(0, Random.Range(0, 36) * 10, 0);
}
```

I thought that maybe if I destroy them (like below) after a second it may work, but it doesn't; I destroy myself.

```
Destroy(treeObj, 1);
```

Comment: This code just shows how you're generating the trees. Can you show us how you tried destroying them?

Comment: Thats the question I dont know how to destroy them.This script is a part of long script attached to camera which creates tree's and endless roads.I tried this but failed.I edited the post and added the not working code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are having problems Destroying the correct object, in this case a tree.

So create a class for the tree, `Tree`. Then attach it to your tree prefab. Inside it you want to check how far away you are from the line of view.

```
public class Tree : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position) > 500)
            Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont destroy them , it takes on your performance , and there is no need for that .

instead lookup how to disable and gameobject, becouse then you just need to have a list/array and then you have x number of gameobjects in the list , and when they dont need to be in the scene you disable it and put it in the back of the list , and then you just turn it back on when your game needs to use it again ...

Then you dont have to keep instanciating a gameobject to your game again and again

Nikolai

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty game object as a child of the camera, then attach a box collider on it with `is trigger` true. The empty game object will always follow the camera because it is the child.

Getting outside of sight just means that the trees are getting outside of camera view, so you can destroy them when they exit the trigger.

So here's the steps you need to take:

1. Create empty game object as child of camera
2. Put a box collider on it with `is trigger` set to true, position it so that it fits the camera view.
3. Add script to it with function [`OnTriggerExit(Collider other)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html)
4. If other is a tree, destroy other.